# Error while running a react native expo application in the release mode. a .apk file

Tags: react-native, expo, apk

When running the application in the debugging mode - on emulator - it runs fine, when running it on the phone - .apk file - it crashes and gives this message in the console.

> There was an error fetching the Expo development certificate, falling back to cached certificate

I tried erasing the cache of the project and eliminating any unnecessary files from the project and it didn't work.